# generate 16-bit color map in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, colormap, color-depth

I would like to colorize a 16-bit depth image with a RGB [colormap](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/tutorials/colors/colormaps.html) in matplotlib. Technically, 3 channels with 8 bit per channel should be enough to have distinct rgb values for all 2^16 possible depth values.

A standard color map 'viridis' does result in <1000 distinct values even though the original depth image had more than twice of that.

I tried creating the colormap with a larger number of samples `plt.get_cmap('viridis', 2**16)`, but it is still not enough.

Some code to describe what I am trying to do:

```py
def depth_to_rgb(path):   
    depth_map = Image.open(path)
    pixel = np.array(depth_map)
    pixel = (pixel - np.min(pixel)) / np.ptp(pixel)
    cm = plt.get_cmap('viridis', 2**16)
    pixel_colored = np.uint8(np.rint(cm(pixel) * 255))[:, :, :3]
    return Image.fromarray(pixel_colored)
```

I can slightly increase the number of distinct values in the map by creating a custom cm, but it is still not enough:

```py
cm = mlp.colors.LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list("",
["red", "green", "yellow"], N=2**16)
```

Is there a colormap with enough values or how could I create one?
Solutions related to the Pillow Image Library are also appreciated.

EDIT

Apparently (thanks to [ImportanceOfBeingErnest](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4124317/)) the resulting colormap has indeed 2**16 values, but `np.uint8(np.rint(cm(pixel) * 255))` caused some of them to fall on the same colors. I only printed the number of distinct colors in the resulting image. I guess I have to do a somehow different mapping, but the original question is answered.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Viridis has 256 colors. It is a `ListedColormap`, which means when resampling it, it will still give you a maximum of the initial number of colors. So `plt.get_cmap('viridis', 2**16)` will still get you the 256 initial colors.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.colors as mcolors

cmap = plt.get_cmap("viridis", 2**16)
a = cmap(np.linspace(0,1,2**16))
print(len(a))
print(len(np.unique(a, axis=0)))
```

prints

```
65536
256
```

But `LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list` with a larger N should work.

```
cmap = mcolors.LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list("", ["red", "green", "yellow"], N=2**16)
a = cmap(np.linspace(0,1,2**16))
print(len(a))
print(len(np.unique(a, axis=0)))
```

prints

```
65536
65536
```

If you wanted a viridis colormap with 2^16 entries, you can still interpolate in between the existing 256 colors,

```
cmap = mcolors.LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list("", plt.cm.viridis.colors, N=2**16)
```

this would result in 65536 colors as above.